# Como faço para salvar o Menu do meu jogo (C#)

Tags: c#

ola, estou tendo um probleminha na hora de salvar as configurações no menu do meu jogo, as resoluções e qualidade ao aperta o botão salvar, ele salva. o problema e que eu fiz uma botão que abre um painel com outros 2 botoes, ate ai tudo bem. esses botoes definem se o jogo fica em "português" ou em "inglês", só que não sei como fazer para salvar essa alteração no meu script, pois o script "Menu" se relaciona com o Script "Menu Pause" ou seja preciso basicamente de um modo que salve a alteração ai do menu, as demais coisas como resolução, qualidade,áudio salvam certinho.